# Internet connection In ubuntu

Tags: internet

When installing  new updates or downloading some items in Net,my Ubuntu is sating"failed to connect internet". No matter how much I tried to fix it, they were all useless. Can you help me fix it

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: You need to specify what type of connection, is this problem all of a sudden happened or it is happening with a fresh install. 
also, please post the output of 
    uname -a

Answer (score 0):

if wifi is connected but no internet.

on the commmand line type:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54m
```

hit enter

try browsing now
it worked like a charm for me

if you want a permanent solution you have to make a script out of it